# Get the real filepath of any file in Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, filepath, android-file

I have an app which I can select an image from the device Gallery.  I need to get the real filepath of the file to upload the file to a remote server.  I have this working successfully with images only, but I wish to expand my app to include any filetype.  My current code fails when trying to get the filepath of a non image.  My code so far:

```
String filepath = "";
try {
  String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
  Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
  if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() != 0) {
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    filepath = cursor.getString(column_index);
  }
}
catch(Exception e) {
  Log.e("Path Error",e.toString());
}
```

I believe my problem lies with "MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA", but I am not sure what to replace it with to handle all file types.

**UPDATE**

OK, worked out that my code is 99% fine. It does work on multiple file types.  The problem is with filenames which contain spaces.  How do I handle this.  I notice that the filepaths are url encoded ie spaces are replaced with "%20".

Comment: like audio and video i can give u is it ohk for u

Comment: It needs to be able to handle any kind of file eg image/audio/video pdf docx etc etc ...

Comment: What is the error you get? Also any `.DATA` in `MediaStore` is just `"_data"` because they all inherit that from [MediaColumns](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.MediaColumns.html#DATA) - that should not be your problem

Comment: You are correct it isn't that which is causing the app to crash, but it is not getting the filepath from uri: filepath returns a null value

Answer (score 4):

Turns out problem was handling filenames which contained URL encoded spaces i.e "%20"

For anyone that is interested my adapted code is as follows:

```
String filepath = "";
String uriPath = uri.toString();

// Handle local file and remove url encoding
if(uriPath.startsWith("file://")) {
  filepath = uriPath.replace("file://","");
  try {
    return URLDecoder.decode(filepath, "UTF-8");
  } 
  catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace()
  }
}

try {
  String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
  Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
  if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() != 0) {
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    filepath = cursor.getString(column_index);
  }
}
catch(Exception e) {
  Log.e("Path Error",e.toString());
}
return filepath;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Uri fileUri=Uri.fromfile(fileObject);

USE: setUrl(Uri.decode(fileUri));
```